# Json returns undifined

Tags: php, json, ajax

Good day guys I have the following login page. Which I access using ajax from my view page. The problem the data that is returned when I try to display on ajax I get an error on the console.

> login.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.success (login.js:35)
>       at i (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2)
>       at z (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4)

```
<?php
ob_start();

function __autoload($classname)
{

    require_once("../../database/$classname.php");
}


class userlogin extends database
{

    private $errors = array();
    private $message = array();
    private $redirect = array();
    private $data = array();
    private $username;
    private $password;

    function login()
    {

        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

            $this->message['error'] = "Please enter username and password";
        } else {

            $this->username = $_POST['username'];
            $this->password = $_POST['password'];


            try {
                $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT adminID,adminEmail,adminPassword,admintype FROM admin where adminEmail = ? ");

                $this->stmt->execute(array(
                    $this->username
                ));

                $this->results = $this->stmt->fetchall();

                if (count($this->results) > 0) {
                    foreach ($this->results as $key => $row) {
                        if (password_verify($this->password, $row['adminPassword'])) {
                            $_SESSION['user']  = $row['adminID'];
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $this->username;
                            $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['admintype'];

                            switch ($row['admintype']) {
                                case 's':
                                    $this->redirect['redirect'] = "seo/index.php?route=home";
                                    break;
                                case 'a':
                                    $this->redirect['redirect'] = "admin/index.php?route=home";
                                    break;
                            }

                            $this->message['success'] = "ok";

                        } else {

                            $this->message['error'] = "Username and password does not match";
                        }

                    }

                } else {

                    $this->message['error'] = "Username does not exist";
                }

            }
            catch (PDOException $pdo) {

                $this->error = $pdo->getMessage();

                error_log($this->error);
            }

            $this->data['message']  = $this->message;
            $this->data['redirects'] = $this->redirect;

            ob_end_clean();

            echo json_encode($this->data);

        }  

    }


}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $login = new userlogin();
    $login->login();
}
?>
```

and my js

```
function proccessLogin(){

        var username = $('input[type="email"][name="email"]').val();
        var password = $('input[type="password"][name="upass"]').val();
        $.ajax({

            type : "POST",
            data : {username:username,password:password},
            url  : "controller/login.php",
            beforeSend : function(){
            $('button').html('Checking...');

            },
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);

                 if(data.message.success == "ok"){
                    $('#results').removeClass('error');
                    $('#results').addClass('success');
                    $('#results').html('login Success, loading user data..');
                    $('button').html('Loading Profile.. i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw"></i>');
                        var redirectUrl = JSON.stringify(data.redirects);
                        redirectUrl = redirectUrl.replace(/[{"":}]/g, '');
                        var url = redirectUrl.replace('redirect','');
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href = "'+ url + '"; ', 6000);
                }else{

                    $('button').html("Sign in");
                    $('#results').removeClass('success');
                    $('#results').addClass('error');
                    $('#results').html(data.message.error);
                }
            },
            error : function(xhr){

                console.log('Error : ' + xhr);
            }
        });
    return false;   
    }
```

Console log results :

```
{"message":{"success":"ok"},"redirects":{"redirect":"seo\/index.php?route=home"}}
```

I want to be able to display the message from the json array if success is ok I will display custome message else display what is coming from response. the problem is property undefined.

line 35 :

`if(data.message.success == "ok"){`

Comment: Your error message says that the error is at line 35. That doesn't match with the code that you posted. Is there more in login.js than you are showing? If so, either show it (if it is relevant) or point out specifically which line in your code is line 35.

Comment: @PatrickQ line 35 : `if(data.message.success == "ok"){`

Comment: jQuery/Javascript _should_ be smart enough to know that the response is json, but just in case it is having trouble, try adding `dataType: "json",` in your ajax setup

Comment: @PatrickQ that worked also added : `encode : true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the response data is String and you need to call

```
$.parseJSON(data);
```

before you can access message and then success

=============

If you want to use **dataType: "json"**, you need to send your JSON as JSON by using PHP's header() function:

```
/* Send as JSON */
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

/* Return JSON */
echo json_encode($json);

/* Stop Execution */
exit;
```

Comment: I used datatype and also added encode : true on ajax. no need to set headers in php and it worked